# Reactive SQS Listener

Tags: java, rx-java, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactive-streams

I am implementing a reactive SQS listener and I am facing a problem with nested subscriptions.

This is how my listener looks like

```
  @PostConstruct
  public void listener() {
    Mono<ReceiveMessageResponse> receiveMessageResponseMono =
        Mono.fromFuture(
            () ->
                sqsAsyncClient.receiveMessage(
                    ReceiveMessageRequest.builder()
                        .queueUrl(queueUrl)
                        .maxNumberOfMessages(MAX_NUMBER_OF_MESSAGES)
                        .waitTimeSeconds(WAIT_TIME_IN_SECONDS)
                        .build()));

    receiveMessageResponseMono
        .repeat()
        .retry()
        .map(ReceiveMessageResponse::messages)
        .map(Flux::fromIterable)
        .flatMap(messageFlux -> messageFlux)
        .subscribe(
            message -> {
              boolean isProcessed;

              isProcessed = process(message.body(), message.attributesAsStrings());

              if (isProcessed) {
                sqsAsyncClient.deleteMessage(
                    DeleteMessageRequest.builder()
                        .queueUrl(queueUrl)
                        .receiptHandle(message.receiptHandle())
                        .build());
              }
            });
  }
```

And the process method:

```
  Boolean process(String message, Map<String, String> attributes) {
    reactiveCrudRepository
        .findById(1)
        .subscribe(b -> log.info("Fetched item {}", b.getId()));
    return true;
  }
```

Now the problem is that I need data from a reactive repository and parent subscription doesn't wait for the child subscription to complete and most of the time I don't get this log `Fetched item`. I can't return a Mono from the function since the process method should be generic and any event can be processed and within the process method, I need to use reactive rest-client and DB client.

I am new to reactive programming so I am not sure how I can solve this or if I am following an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 1):

As you can correctly guess, the `findById(1)` operation does not have time to complete. The reason is that `.subscribe` kicks off the process and returns immediately.

> I can't return a Mono from the function since the process method
> should be generic

Well, if you want to use a reactive repository you have to return `Mono`:

```java
 Mono<Boolean> process(String message, Map<String, String> attributes) {
    return reactiveCrudRepository
             .existsById(1); //consider using existsById instead of findById
  }
```

And then use it like this:

```java
 .filterWhen(messageFlux -> process(...))
 .flatMap(message -> sqsAsyncClient.deleteMessage(
                DeleteMessageRequest.builder()
                    .queueUrl(queueUrl)
                    .receiptHandle(message.receiptHandle())
                    .build()))
  .subscribe();
```

**Edit**

> I would always have to return a Mono of that data type but data can be
> different on different types of events.

You could do it exactly as you would with the simple Java method. Assuming you have two types of events: `PlainEvent`, `AdvancedEvent` and a parent class `Event`:

```java
class Event {
    private String id;
}

class PlainEvent extends Event {
    private String name;
}

class AdvancedEvent extends Event {
    private String name;
}
```

The return type would be `Mono<Event>`:

```java
Mono<Event> process() {
    return Mono.just(new PlainEvent("id", "name"));
}
```

```java
.flatMap(event -> process())
.flatMap(event -> {
    if (event instanceof PlainEvent) {
        log.info("plain {}", event);
    } else {
        log.info("advanced {}", event);
    }

    return reactiveCrudRepository.save(event);
})
```

Comment: but if I want to store some data using a reactive repository on an event how would I do that? I would always have to return a Mono of that data type but data can be different on different types of events.

Comment: @Professor edit made